# Display image in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, image, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am working on `Windows Phone 8 app` I have images in `Resources\Graphics\` within the app.I am trying to display the images from this folder.

`<img src=Resources/Graphics/Image1.png>` but its not displaying.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the exact path and file-name of the image, not just the folder path.

Example:

Assuming you have an image called "`Image.png`" inside your Resources\Graphics folder, you can then bind to it like:

```
<img Source="/Resources;component/Graphics/Image.png"/>
```

Comment: As i said before i have added the images in the folder `Resources/Graphics/Image1.png` and image build action set to `Content`

Comment: i have a string `html.Append("<p id=\"p1\"><img src=/Resources;component/Graphics/Image.png/")`

Comment: remove the extra forward slash after png

Comment: Also, is this HTML or WPF? your tag says WPF, but by the looks of it, it appears to be html

Comment: Its HTML i have removed and this is how its now `html.Append("<p id=\"p1\"><img source=\"Resources;component/Graphics/").Append(Image).Append("\" ")`

Comment: When i print this `html` in console its like this `<p id="p1"><img source="/Resources;component/Graphics/image.png"`